# Android Java Bcrypt library password doesn't match database encrypted password

Tags: java, android, sqlite, bcrypt

So I know many people ask why their encrypted password doesn't match with the input, but I couldn't find any specific case as for my situation.

I am using the Bcrypt Library of https://github.com/patrickfav/bcrypt in my Android Sqlite project.

When I use his example as follow:

it logs fine and says that it the passwords match. But, when I call this verification from another method with the same password, it always says "false". Can somebody explain me why it happens and how can I fix it ?

```
String bcryptHashString = BCrypt.withDefaults().hashToString(12, password.toCharArray());
// $2a$12$US00g/uMhoSBm.HiuieBjeMtoN69SN.GE25fCpldebzkryUyopws6
    ...
BCrypt.Result result = BCrypt.verifyer().verify(password.toCharArray(), bcryptHashString);
// result.verified == true
```

Comment: Could you share your own code as well?

Comment: I use the same example so there is no difference in the code... I call the verify method on btn click

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you generate a new salt with each call of the following line:

```java
String bcryptHashString = BCrypt.withDefaults().hashToString(12, password.toCharArray());
```

You will need to store this somewhere and than use it to verify the password. By using a new salt it will always fail the check.